# C# - DataSet DataGridView Clear duplicate

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sql-server-2008

Im beginner on c# , I have problem is when i execute the following code i got duplication

```
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from panier", cnx);
        dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dap.Fill(ds, "panier");
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["panier"];*
```

**I need to execute this code every click on button "ADD"**

> The question is how can i check if ds.Tables["panier"] empty or not so
>   i can execute .Clear()

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't bother checking. If there is data, your call to `Clear` will clear the result. If there is no data, the call to `Clear` will have no real effect, but as it's not a computationally expensive process, it will finish very quickly. I would simply always call `Clear` as you're always loading all the data from `panier` when the button is clicked.

Comment: Check if `ds.Tables["panier"].Rows.Count==0`

Comment: if i add the code `ds.Tables["panier"].Clear()` the program is buged because the table is already clear

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i got this error when i tried ur solution **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
if(ds.Tables["panier"] != null && ds.Tables["panier"].Rows.Count > 0)
{
   ds.Tables["panier"].Clear();
}
```

You have to check two conditions:

1. The table must exist.
2. The number of rows greater than zero.

Comment: THANKKKKKKKKKK YOU SO MUCH , WORKS finally thx bro really i i appreciate it